# What's the use of the Name parameter in RouteAttribute?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Looking at this:

```
[Route("", Name = "GetChanges")]
```

What's the use of the Name parameter? The only useful usage of this is I am able to refer to the action when calling CreatedAtRoute such that:

```
return CreatedAtRoute("GetChanges", new { id = model.ChangeId }, model);
```

So why and what's the use case for the "Name" in RouteAttribute?

Comment: Didn’t you just call out the use? It is to refer to it by name unambiguously.

Comment: That's the only usage for it? I know for GET, at least I would use it when calling CreatedAtRoute, because I can refer to it. If by unambiguous, I think that would make sense for GET. But if I add the Name for PUT, POST, PATCH, when would I ever refer to it? Any example use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the use case is simply ambiguity resolution. If there are more than two actions on a controller that may qualify somehow the name is not ambiguous. I would prefer not to use a name unless needed, but I could see organizations adopt the ‘though shall use names to resolve unambiguously” approach as well. Count me as not a proponent, but the mechanism is there should you need it.

Answer (score 0):

WebAPI by itself doesn't allows function overloading. So if there are two functions with same name but differing in parameters (overloading within the implementing class), the *name* attribute allows for those methods to be called by a specific names.

Along with, the class naming may be governed by different coding standards, whereas route names are those exposed to client, hence may have to be following different guidelines